# Chromium 50 WebGL support on Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie, chromium

I've installed Chromium like described
[here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121195)

The I've set the flag to "Override software rendering list" in chrome://flags and restarted the browser - still WebGL doesn't work.

This is the output of chrome://gpu
[image: This is the output of chrome://gpu]

See the command line args listed there - what is that --disable-gpu doing there? Could that be the issue? How do I launch Chromium without that flag?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it out - the specific version I got from mentioned link has preset arguments:

> "GPU is disabled by default. If you are using the OpenGL driver,
>   remove the flag in /etc/chromium-browser/default"

After removing that line all works as expected.